# Warped UV for simple model

Tags: uv

[*Update: The original had lots of extra vertices for some unknown reason. I recreated the object from scratch to remove them. `.blend` file and images updated.*]

I'm trying to create a UV map, and it always ends up warped.

Are multiple independent seams allowed? If so, I'm at wits' end.

I tried creating the object a number of different ways. This particular one was created from a cube, moved z face, extrude x face, extrude y face, limited disolve, inset z face, extrude inset z face.

Complete beginner!

[`Tile9d.blend`](http://www.adaelis.com/misc/temp/Tile9d.blend)

[image: Mesh with seams]
[image: Warped UV map]

Expected:

[image: Expected result]

(I can always condense that by splitting it into two and flipping and rotating one of them.)

Comment: Are you marking seams?

Comment: @Ron Jensen, Yes, you can seem them in the first image

Comment: I see that now. Does "Smart UV Project" do what you want?

Comment: @Ron Jensen, That creates a [bunch of individual pieces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oedRX.png) (but no warping). Is that the only way? It would be a pain to move each one into position.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, Why did you delete the answer that showed how to solve the problem??? And why did you put a (corrupted) copy of it in the question??? (Removed!)

Comment: Hi @ikegami and welcome, your post seemed more like a comment or an update to your question than an actual full answer. We expect a certain degree of quality and thorough explanation of the steps taken from an answer, see [How to write good answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). If you think you can improve your post feel free to copy paste from the deleted answer and paste it to a new one while improving it with further explanation.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, Oddly, you left an answer with no solution and no explanation. And while I believe the steps described in my solution were clear even to a newcomer, I've just made them clearer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are UV unwrapping, you're basically trying to flatten out a box. You can cut seams around all six faces, but that leaves separated parts. Try to find the edges where the geometry has to spread and mark those as seams, like this:

[image: Another way of cutting seams]

You can see I made seams down the 45 degree bevels, and just cut the bottom out separately.

After removing all the extra geometry it becomes much easier to achieve the UV layout you wanted:
[image: Second unwrapping]

Comment: That's still pretty warped. You're literally squishng faces where there isn't space. Any reason it can't produce the result I've added to my question?

Comment: I just noticed you have a lot of extra vertices. Your original model has 40 vertices, but you only need 24 for this figure. There are some around the centerline. Select those and dissolve them, then merge by distance the rest.

Comment: Re "*I just noticed you have a lot of extra vertices*", Ah, thanks, but it didn't help. I have no idea how so many extra got created. Your new picture is close, but removing the extra vertices and merging the rest by distance had no effect.